# what means "pointer was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

There are many errors in my codes. 
But i don't know about wrong things...
There are common error massages such that "invalid use of template-name 
‘node’ without an argument list", "‘head_ptr’ was not declared in this 
scope", "‘tail_ptr’ was not declared in this scope",
"‘t’ was not declared in this scope" ,
"template argument 1 is invalid", "expected type-specifier before ‘Node’"
I don't think my overall code is wrong. 
But too many error make me to think 
all of composition of coding is error.. 
It is a part of all code.

[error explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20rfD.png)

```
template <typename T>
Node* Node<t>::getNext(void)
{ return next; }

template <typename T>
class List
{
    private:
        Node* head_ptr; Node* tail_ptr; int numOfItems;
    public:
        List(); //constructor
        int size(void); bool isEmpty(void);
        void insertTail(T x);
        void removeHead(void);
        Node<T>* getHead(void);
        Node<T>* getTail(void);
        void insert_with_priority(T x);
};

template <typename T>
List<T>::List()
{ head_ptr = NULL; tail_ptr = NULL; numOfItems = 0; }

template <typename T>
void List<T>::insertTail(T x){
    Node<t>* newTail = new Node(x);
    tail_ptr->setNext(newTail);
    tail_ptr = newTail;
    numOfItems++;
}

template <typename T>
void List<T>::removeHead(void){
    if(numOfItems == 0)
        return 0;
    if(numOfItems == 1){ //i.e. headptr == tail_ptr
        delete head_ptr; head_ptr = NULL; tail_ptr = NULL;
```

'
   Please give me many feedback.

Comment: Please *copy-paste* the errors, as text, complete and in full. Then *edit your question* to include that full copy-paste. And please [(re)read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Even though your question is incomplete, I'll help you with *one* of the errors (and it might solve other follow-up errors as well)...

Lets take the lines

```
template <typename T>
Node* Node<t>::getNext(void)
{ return next; }
```

You say that the `getNext` function returns a pointer to `Node`. But, in this instance what *is* `Node`? It's not a class or a type, it's a *template* for a class or type. It's not complete. You need to specify the full and complete class or type:

```
template <typename T>
Node<T>* Node<t>::getNext(void)
{ return next; }
```

Note the return-type which is now a full *class*.